# why not proper show my form field in stackblitz

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular11, stackblitz

This form is working fine when the first time I created but after reopening the project then it is not showing properly.

if anyone can find this problem, I appreciate you. thank you.

[image]

below link is my angular project in stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-login-form-with-validation-beiqja?

Comment: check in console some error is coming or not

Comment: error is not shown in the console

Comment: What "not showing properly" means? What is your expectation?

Comment: properly means shows like angular material form field

Comment: in the above form, the button showing properly but the input field, not show properly

Comment: For me, it opened correctly every time. I opened it couple of time, also refreshed it it was working as expected. Could you plz try to open your form in ```incognito``` mode. Their might be some cache issue probably.

Comment: It looks like the `<button>` or the `<mat-icon>` is increasing the size of the inputs

Comment: @BhaveshAjani, check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, couldn't identify your problem.
But I've recreated the working solution successfully at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fjjg5v?file=src/app/app.component.ts) and [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gmdg4?file=src%2Findex.html).

[image]